# Read Date data from .txt file

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I have data in two columns and ~500,000 rows. The first column is A, in date form:

`mm/dd/yy hh/mm/ss`

However Excel doesn't read it as Date unless I select the cell and try to modify it, then it becomes automatically a date format and I can plot it adequately. (I have tried changing the data type but nothing changes unless I select the cell.)

How can I do that for the whole data set?

Comment: can you post a few rows of the data? that way we can analize it and try to get it to work

Comment: `hh/mm/ss` is what's tripping it and making Excel treat it as a string. Insert a column after column A, and do `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,8))+TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A2,8),"/",":"))`, fill down, apply date/time number format. Looks right? Select column B, copy, paste special/values onto column A.

Comment: @pnuts I was surprised to find out that it does.. however `DATEVALUE` doesn't understand it.

Comment: @pnuts oh, I'm on Excel 2010 (32-bit) here. Will try to remember to test this on the latest Excel 2016 (64-bit) insider build at home =)

Comment: thank you all for your help, @mathieu-guindon : thanks I tried it and it works